# Getting a Variable back from a Nested Function that uses google.script.run

Tags: javascript, nested-function

I'm sure I'm close to solving this. I have done some research and keep finding examples that say I can use local variable inside of nested functions but only some stuff on the other way round (getting a variable back out of a nested function). On top of that Im working with google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()  which confuses the matter (or at least it confuses me)

I need to get xRates back so I can use it inside of the function "updateSidebarValues". I have tried to use closures but TBH, when adding the withSuccessHandler element I dont really understand how.

I wrote this instead: (its wrong, but I must be close?)

```
function updateSidebarValues(salesTotals) {

       var valueToPass = document.getElementById('reportSelect').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(RatesGetter).getXrates(valueToPass);

 function RatesGetter(xRates) {
  alert('YAY!!!! This is the variable we need from Code.gs : ' + xRates);
 }

   ..... Do other stuff with xRates

}
```

my Alert works... It shows the correct result from my Code file... but when I try to use xRates later, tells me its undefined :(

Comment: Where is that `callback()` coming from?

Comment: @Luca oops, that was left over from another experiment - I have edited and removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have more than a scoping problem. `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()` appears to be asynchronous, so the results it gets won't happen in the same event loop. So even if you could address the scope issue, you would be trying to access the values before they are defined. You could just make another function and call it from within your callback. For example:

```
function updateSidebarValues(salesTotals) {

    var valueToPass = document.getElementById('reportSelect').value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(RatesGetter).getXrates(valueToPass);

    function RatesGetter(xRates) {
        alert('YAY!!!! This is the variable we need from Code.gs : ' + xRates);
        doOtherStuff(xRates)
    }
    function doOtherStuff(xRates) {
        //… Do other stuff with xRates
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could just do your other stuff right in `RatesGetter()`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, here: `function RatesGetter(xRates) {...}` `xRates` is a parameter of the function and you can access it only inside this method. And it will be passed inside `callback(xRates)`, but it will not be accessible where you wrote "..... Do other stuff with xRates".

Comment: Thanks for that... so... Are you saying that its impossible to get data back out of a Nested Function?

Comment: @DavidTonkin, you can do that only if Nested Function will return it. As I understand, you want to pass `xRates` to Nested Function and get back `newXRates` and use it further?

Comment: Dont need to pass xRates to the nested function, it comes from my code.gs.

I really only have the nested function because that's how the example I found to get a variable from code.gs to clients-side did it.... This is all inside of larger function that does other things....  What I need is the main function I started with to grab xRates from code.gs then continue doing everything else it has to do...